# Anaconda prompt and conda command not working

Tags: python, conda

I was installing `rdkit` package from `https://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html` with conda command.

However, there were some errors and it started to rollback. While doing so, I terminated the command.

After that, the `conda` command seemed to not work at all.

```
C:\Users\user>where conda
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

```
C:\Users\user>conda --version
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: This is my C:\Users\uesr\Anaconda3\Scripts]

This pic is my `C:\Users\uesr\Anaconda3\Scripts`

I've added `anaconda` and `anaconda\scripts` location to my `path`, so it's not a `path` problem.

I'm using `windows10`

Reinstalling anaconda would be the best solution?

Comment: will reinstalling my anaconda, delete the environments i created? is there an easy way to re create the environment?

Comment: How exactly did you install the package? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can please do that, Few months back similar issue was faced by me too. I looked a lot for solutions of this issue, found many, some of them worked too but the problem reappeared after installing some other package. Best solution will be to reinstall anaconda. If not willing to do so, then do comment, I'll provide you with the solution, but I won't be able to assure you that it will solve the issue permanently.

Answer (score 1):

first delete the path and uninstall anaconda

then again reinstall it
then again add path in system environment variable
[image: you can find image here]
then press ok in all windows

Comment: IIRC the Conda docs explicitly say not to modify the PATH manually.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens as Path is not set.

My Anaconda is places here
[My Path of Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3J70.png)

You need to go to
Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advanced system settings  & then ‘Environment Variables’  and add your Path of Ananconda

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNxgj.png)

Click on 'Environment Variables'

[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtMCb.png)

Comment: These pictures are too small to see anything.

Comment: Do not include links to images, either imbed the images or use text instead.